# How to configure a separately hosted message broker with MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm quite new to the usage of a message broker and thought I understood the principle, but when getting down to it, I get the impression that I'm missing a link somewhere.

What we want to do is to have a separately hosted message broker, so we can containerize it and possibly have a different implementation (such as RabbitMQ vs Azure Service Bus) in different environment. To get the proper abstraction we've decide to implement this using MassTransit.
The intent is then that we have multiple separate web services that would serve as producers and/or consumers that connect to the broker. We would prefer these to not have a dependency on RabbitMQ specifically, as the implementation could change.

I've started from [this sample in the MassTransit documentation](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ConsoleService), which I got to work and then started moving the publish and consume configuration to other solutions, but that's where it went wrong; I was unable to acquire an endpoint to publish to, so I moved the publish code back to the original project so it could be registered straight from the bus. I have an IConsumer implementation in another API, but for some reason, I never receive the published message.

So, right now, my code is the following:

Configuration of hosted service bus:

```
ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<ServiceBusConfig>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ServiceBus"));

                services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddBus(provider =>
                    {
                        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbit =>
                        {
                            var host = rabbit.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                            {
                                h.Username("guest");
                                h.Password("guest");
                            });
                            rabbit.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
                        });
                    });
                });

                services.AddHostedService<MassTransitHostedService>();
                services.AddHostedService<PublishService>();
            })
```

The MassTransitHostedService is just an IHostedService that takes in an IBusControl and starts it.
The PublishService takes in an IPublishEndpoint and calls

```
_endpoint.Publish<MyContract>(new { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() });
```

On the consumer service side, I have an implementation of IConsumer that I attempt to wire up like so

```
AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                var host = config.Host("localhost", "/",
                    h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
            });
            cfg.AddConsumer<MyConsumer>();
            bus.Start();
        });
```

It's not ideal that I have to specifically call CreateUsingRabbitMq, as that has the dependency that I'm trying to avoid, but I don't know of another way to connect to a specific host. Regardless, it doesn't work, as the Consume method is never entered.

So, I'm sure I'm missing something, but I don't know what and it's driving me up the wall.
First of all my question is, is it possible to have a setup like this? Namely having the broker hosted in a separate application and having multiple external publishers and consumers? Most things I can find either have everything in the same project by way of example, or just split the producer and consumer.

If so, what's the code that I need to implement to configure them correctly and can it be done without using a specific RabbitMQ bus?

Do the producers and consumers even really need a bus at all, as they should technically just connect to some arbitrary endpoint and push/receives messages to and from it, respectively? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something in the theory behind it.

Thanks for any insight you would be able to give.

Comment: RMQ or another broker is infrastructure, which cannot be abstracted because each infrastructure piece has its specifics. From the application point of view, which can use `IConsumer` and `IPublishEndpoint` it's broker-agnostics. So, it's up to your application design to do a clear separation to enable what you want.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev so you're saying I can't really wrap the broker in a separate application with its configuration and then have other applications connect to it, but each consumer and/or producer should set up their own bus to an existing broker?

Comment: I am saying that your `Startup.cs` file will be different between brokers. Or some sort of factory that creates and returns the `IBusControl` instance that your `ConfigureServices` method uses. The _application_ itself should not really use anything more than the interfaces I mentioned.

Comment: That's fair, so you're confirming that every application involved will need a reference to the specific broker implementation, whether directly or indirectly.
We were hoping to avoid this by using MassTransit in the first place, but I suppose there's no way around it.